# String extraction from another string using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to extract values from XML.My xml file contains a field for product "Description" that consists of Product bardcode, packets and pallets.

I want to extract only Pck (it could be any number from 1-999).

My xml attribute(Description) field values:

```
  Description="5038135129483  &#xD;&#xAPck: 4   Plt: 120"
```

Here

```
 Barcode=5038135129483   
 Number of Packets(Pck)=4
 Number of Palletes(Plt)=120

 $pieces = substr($WhatDescription,19,20);
```

I have tried substr function to extract from string but it doesn't give me accurate results as the barcode 's length varies and I have got html characters in my XML. Could you advise what shall I do to extract Pck from above string in such away that my extraction wont depend upon html characters and barcode's length.

Comment: http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php

Comment: You should be using an XML parser, not regexes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
<?php
   $text = "5038135129483  &#xD;&#xAPck: 4   Plt: 120";
   $newtext = strstr($text,'Pck:');
   echo $final = trim(substr($newtext,0,stripos($newtext,'Plt:')));
?>
```

Working code: http://codepad.org/3sbfIim8

Comment: @GBDthanks.But this code retrieves anything that comes after "4" as well.How can avoid this in my string??

Comment: can you paste your complete string ?

Comment: @GBD.Thanks.here it is: $text="5038135129483  &#xD;&#xAPck: 4 &nbsp;  Plt: 120 itemcode:91";

Comment: You can use strip_tags() and replace &nbsp; here is example: http://codepad.org/iuc5piWv